# jQuery draggable/droppable: access to original element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm dragging elements from one unordered list to another:

```
$('ul#drag li').draggable({ helper: 'clone' });
$('ul#drop').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.sourceElement.css(... ...);
    }
});
```

I want to mark **already dragged elements** in source list (but still allow dragging them), **how do I access them through jQuery chain?**

I guess I can set `id` attribute on the dragged element, and when dropping, the cloned element would have the same `id`, which I can use in finding the original, but I'm sure there's a nicer solution.

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder why I did not notice that the following works, the first time I tried it:

```
ui.draggable.css('whatever');
```

It's even [documented](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#overview):

> ui.draggable - current draggable element, a jQuery object.

Comment: the interesting question becomes: how to remove the style when the object is dragged out of the target again...

Comment: @xtofl: I used `data()` to store the id of the source element on drop event, and when dragging element out of second list (back to first), use that stored data to find the original...

Answer (score 6):

`e.target` refers to the original element

Comment: $(e.target).method() = Do whatever you do with htmlnode